# Mudar estilo FacesMessages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Como é mostrado na figura, as `FacesMessages` tem a seguinte formatação padrão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível alterar os estilos do fundo e das fontes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode manipular praticamente todos elementos da tela apenas inspecionando elementos com o firebug ou ferramentas dos próprios browsers, um exemplo se quisesse alterar as mensagens de erros, seria:

```
.ui-growl-error, .ui-growl-fatal, .ui-messages .ui-messages-error, .ui-message.ui-message-error, .ui-messages .ui-messages-fatal, .ui-message.ui-message-fatal {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-color: #red;
        color: #000000;
    }
```

Essa é a parte que mais me desagrada nesses beans para faces, sempre precisa ficar sobrescrevendo o CSS, e muitas vezes precisa fica forçando o CSS a usar a propriedade com !important, mas tudo é possivel fazer.